# Vim <ctrl-w> does not work on existing text, custom compilation of vim7.3

Tags: vim, mode

I am on a ubuntu 10.04 machine. The installed vim7.2 works as expected in insert mode for `<ctrl-w,h,u>` but my custom compiled vim7.3.744 shows a strange behaviour:

Starting vim with an empty buffer (cursor indicated by `|`):

```
~|
```

When I switch to insert mode, and type a few letters the commands `<ctrl-w,h,u>` work just fine:

```
~adsf|<ctrl-w>
```

=>

```
~|
```

However, when I leave insert mode after typing and enter insert mode again and press `<ctrl-w,h,u>` nothing happens:

```
~adsf|<Esc>

Pressing A to enter insert mode again

~adsf|<ctrl-w>
```

=>

```
~asdf|
```

If I should show `:ver` I can do this.

**Update**

Note: the vim setting `backspace` is set in $VIMRUNTIME/debian.vim which /usr/bin/vim7.2 uses for startup.

Comment: Yes, `:version` would be useful. But if there is nothing in your buffer/line, it's quite normal for `<C-w>` and friends to do *nothing*, don't you think?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Hope my edit of my question made my problem  clearer. Of course on an empty line nothing would happen, but that was not what I was talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "`:set backspace+=start`".  You may want to go the whole way and do "`:set backspace=indent,eol,start`".

See "`:help 'backspace'`" (the single-quotes are meant to be typed).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That solved my problem: within `/usr/bin/vim` `:set backspace?` gives `backspace=indent,eol,start`, and within `$HOME/usr/bin/vim`, `set backspace?` gives `backspace=`. I guess there is a system-wide vimrc file which my custom $HOME/usr/bin/vim is not considering. Sometimes the solutions are somewhere unexpected and simple.